Why close 5-year old questions?
There seems to me to have been a minor spate of close votes on old questions.  The most recent example, prompting this meta post, is this question.
I'm not really seeing the point of closing old questions that have been sitting around gathering dust for a few years. Such have apparently been perfectly acceptable, until suddenly they're not. It all seems pretty arbitrary.

Doesn't bother me. This is not a forum, but a Q&A, so questions have the same relevance now as they did. This means that a question's age has nothing to do with whether it gets closevoted or not.

It seems strange that it takes 5 years to determine a question is unsuitable.

I actually like the linked question. But I agree that age has nothing to do with it - if something should be closed then the fact that it wasn't closed 5 years ago just means people didn't care as much about it then. Similarly, not all old furniture is valuable - some is just old junk.
